# How to enter password in mysql5.5 using batch script?

Tags: mysql, batch-file

i have written a batch script but it still ask me for a password. i want to enter it automatically. please help me

here is my batch script :

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
c:
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"

mysql -u root -p root
```

but still in output it ask for a password as:

> Enter Password :

**i got the answer. for that find below my comment**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved Got the solution

> c:
>
> cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"
>
> mysql -uroot -proot -e "delete from db.tablename where columnname =
>   'something';

The problem is In this line `"setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion"` 
This should be deleted. and the code runs smoothly :)

Answer (score 6):

You can't have a space between the option and the password. So it should be:

`mysql -u root -proot`

Or use `--password=root`

Comment: nope, it gives error 1045. in mysql5.5 there is a space between -p and root.   as a result my query not solved yet :(

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password would indicate you do need a space. And 1045 is Access Denied. Are you sure its the correct username/password?

Comment: hey i got the solution. i just add username and password to the mysql exe files properties. in that in "Target" textbox i wrote this line : "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql.exe" "--defaults-file=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini" "-uroot" "-proot!"

Answer (score 4):

For other googlers like me, I'll add my solution.
Unfortunately, official documentation doesn't tell this clearly

### Short parameters like these didn't work to me and prompted for password

```
mysqldump -uroot -p "qwerty" mybase > Z:\mybase.sql
```

### With "full" name parameters it worked, just warning about this action as insecure

```
mysqldump  --user="root" --password="qwerty" mybase > Z:\mybase.sql

echo 'Backup OK' > mysql_dump.log
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot do this using the mysql bin, but mysqladmin can.

See the docs here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqladmin.html

Comment: i do not have access to mysqladmin. so is there any other way

Answer (score 0):

-ppassword displays warning

> Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html

**Solution:** You can use cnf options file

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html

linux:

```
echo -e "[client]\nhost=mysqlhost\nport=3306\nuser=root\npassword=${ROOT_PASS}" > root.cnf
mysql --defauls-file=root.cnf -e "SELECT * FROM users;" ${MYDB}
```

windows:

Ship root.cnf file with batch script and run

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql" --defauls-file=root.cnf -e "SELECT * FROM users;" %MYDB%
```

Answer (score 0):

try this create a file for password .pw and below command works in batch fine.
mysql --default-file=C:\path*.pw -u %username% blah blah..

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use MySQL options files.

MySQL 5.5 makes use of the .my.cnf file, you just need to supply your username and password. This approach means you can login to mysql just by typing `mysql` in your script and the .my.cnf file will fill in the rest; Here's how:

Create a .my.cnf file in the home directory of the user which will run the script. The contents should look like the following code block, swapping out *your_user* and *your_password* for their actual values.

```
[client]
user=your_user
password=your_password
```

It's prudent to change the permission of this file to either 400 or 600, this will mean only your user and root will be able to see the file.

```
chmod 600 .my.cnf
```

You're all set!

#### N.B.

From version 5.6 onwards you can use the mysql_config_editor utility, which generates a .mylogin.cnf, it has the same result as the above apporoach with the added benefit that the password will be encrypted by the utility.

#### Links

MySQL 5.5
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/password-security-user.html

MySQL 5.6+
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, put it in a .bat file, and change the password with yours.

```
@echo OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
C:
cd "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\"
mysql.exe  --user="root" --password="the password"
```